# Setting a default child table view controller for segmented control

Tags: ios, swift

I can use the segmented control to switch between child table view controllers within a container view, but it doesn't show the cells of the first table view controller when I enter the scene for some reason. I have my segment index defaulted at 0, so it shows the highlight on the first segment, but it does not correspondingly show the cells.
Here is the code for the segmentedControl and container view:

```
import UIKit

class BarMainViewController: UIViewController {

let barSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let barItems = ["Newest", "Rewarding", "Saved"]
   let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: barItems)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    return segmentedControl
}()

let containerView: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(barSegmentedControl)
    view.addSubview(containerView)

    setDefaultVC()

    barSegmentedControl.addUnderlineForSelectedSegment()

    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: barSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -49).isActive = true
    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

}

@objc func selectionDidChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    updateView()
    barSegmentedControl.changeUnderlinePosition()
}

private func updateView() {
    if barSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        remove(asChildViewController: BarRewardingViewController())
        remove(asChildViewController: BarSavedViewController())
        add(asChildViewController: BarNewestViewController())
    } else if barSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        remove(asChildViewController: BarNewestViewController())
        remove(asChildViewController: BarSavedViewController())
        add(asChildViewController: BarRewardingViewController())
    } else {
        remove(asChildViewController: BarNewestViewController())
        remove(asChildViewController: BarRewardingViewController())
        add(asChildViewController: BarSavedViewController())
    }
}

private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UITableViewController) {
    // Add Child View Controller
    addChildViewController(viewController)

    // Add Child View as Subview
    containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)

    // Configure Child View
    viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UITableViewController) {
    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    // Remove Child View From Superview
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}

private func setDefaultVC() {
    containerView.addSubview(BarNewestViewController().view)
}
}
```

And here is the code for the table view controller:

```
import UIKit

class BarNewestViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    tableView.register(serviceCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "service")

    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = mainBlue
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "service", for: indexPath)
}
}

class serviceCell: UITableViewCell {
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "NAME"
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Avnier-Heavy", size: 20)

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(nameLabel)
    backgroundColor = lightBlue

    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
}    
}
```

Comment: Are you setting up the TableView programmatically? If so are you setting the constraints? Also, make sure the set the tableViews dataSource and delegate (usually to self).

Answer (score 0):

Because `BarNewestViewController` subclasses `UITableViewController` it automatically follows the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols e.g. `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`. It does NOT however tell the property `tableView` that comes with `UITableViewController` that it's `delegate` and `dataSource` is `BarNewestViewController`.

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```